# How to increase the Firebase hosting request timeout?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have configured my HTTPS cloud function with a longer request timeout to reach 300 seconds, when I am calling this CF using the CF original URL format `https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME` the CF response is always `200 OK` regardless of the its execution time (more than 60s)

However, when I am hosting my CFs on Firebase hosting, if I call my CF using the Firebase Hosting URL and the functions takes more than 60s to execute then I am getting a `502 Bad Gateway`

I am aware of what the documenttation is saying [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Firebase%20Hosting%20is%20subject,than%2060%20seconds%20to%20run.)

> Note: Firebase Hosting is subject to a 60-second request timeout. Even if you configure your HTTPS function with a longer request timeout, you'll still receive an HTTPS status code 504 (request timeout) if your function requires more than 60 seconds to run.

But I wonder if there's any way or workaround to increase this timeout?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function) and you mentioned in the question,

> Note: Firebase Hosting is subject to a 60-second request timeout. Even if you configure your HTTPS function with a longer request timeout, you'll still receive an HTTPS status code 504 (request timeout) if your function requires more than 60 seconds to run.

I would like to inform you that as of now, Firebase Hosting is limited to a 60-second request timeout and there is no way to increase this timeout.

As an alternative you may consider using an [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/flexible-for-standard-users#maximum_request_timeout) environment as it supports a maximum request timeout of 60 minutes stated in the same [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function) you are referring to. If you would like to configure your request timeout to a value greater than 60 seconds to run.

However, you can open an [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features), explaining your problem and requesting this functionality.